# How to wait for async functions in c#

Tags: c#

I have 3 async function that must run together, like this

```
public async Task Fun1()
{
  // do something
}
public async Task Fun2()
{
  // do something
}
public async Task Fun2()
{
  // do something
}
```

in my base function I call this functions
this functions must run together
how to wait for this functions until all complete?

```
public async Task BaseFun()
{
    Fun1()
    Fun2()
    Fun3()
   // do something after Fun1, Fun2 and Fun3 complete
}
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "run together"?

Comment: Do you mean run asynchronously in parallel?

Comment: "run together" that means functions don`t wait for each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public async Task BaseFun()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(Fun1(),
    Fun2(),
    Fun3());
   // do something after Fun1, Fun2 and Fun3 complete
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add await before the functions.

```
public async Task BaseFun()
{
    await Fun1();
    await Fun2();
    await Fun3();
   // do something after Fun1, Fun2 and Fun3 complete
}
```

Comment: Need to be careful when using this kind of pattern in await functions, imagine each of these functions download data from website (each taking about 5 seconds). After first `await` the method will wait for it to complete before proceeding onto take 2. This would mean unnecessary hit on performance.

Comment: This would be the correct pattern _when_ the Fun?() calls are not independent (ie, not threadsafe). The question is not totally clear.

Answer (score 0):

also can do as

```
public async Task BaseFun()
{
    await Fun1();
    await Fun2();
    await Fun3();
    // do something after Fun1, Fun2 and Fun3 complete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Task.WaitAll.

```
var taskArray = new Task[3]
{
    Fun1(),
    Fun2(),
    Fun3()
};
Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
```

BTW, why are your Fun1-3 methods also public when you call them through a public base method?